# In tampermonkey variable urlm behaves differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I write this code in tampermonkey,

```js
var n = document.getElementsByTagName("a").length;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    var urlm = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].href;
    //urlm.replace("#", "");
   // var v = "change('"+urlm+"')";
    // document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].setAttribute("onclick", v);
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){ alert(urlm); ajaxpagefetcher.load("ajax-div",urlm, true); }, false);
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].setAttribute("href", "javascript:alert("+urlm+")");
}
```

when i excute this code i am getting differnt value for **urlm** . Suppose 
*var urlm = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].href;* Here urlm**strong text** returns *http://www.example.\com/page/page3.html*....

But, In this line *addEventListener('click', function(event){ alert(urlm); ajaxpagefetcher.load("ajax-div",urlm, true); }, false);*   **alert(urlm);** shows only *http://www.example.\com/* but here  *page/page3.html* is missing.... But in the next line *javascript:alert("+urlm+")");* it excutes as **javascript:alert("http:/www.example.\com/page/page3).** Please let me know what wrong i am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Value urlm is assigned outside the click event.

Please load urlm in this click event, in other words, copy the line in the click event

```
var urlm = event.target.href;
```

Since urlm is loaded outside the click event, the value in urlm might be different at the time the click event happened.

Your click event could look like

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){ var urlm = event.target.href; alert(urlm); ajaxpagefetcher.load("ajax-div",urlm, true); }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create functions in a loop.

In your situation it's best to create a single function that does the right thing - you are attaching *one* behavior, after all. This function can then be attached to multiple DOM objects.

Make use of the fact that `addEventListener` manages setting `this` to the right object.

```
function ajaxPageFetch(event) {
    // this smells (*)
    var urlm = "change('" + this.href + "')";
    ajaxpagefetcher.load("ajax-div", urlm, true);
}

var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), i;    
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 
    a[i].addEventListener('click', ajaxPageFetch, false);
}
```

---

(*) What if `href` contains single quotes? What exactly does `ajaxpagefetcher.load()` do with `urlm`?